# Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'initial'. Current value: 'visible'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to use Angular2-Material..
I've installed @angular2/material and @angular2/cdk and wanted to use SnackBar..
I've imported the MdSnackBarModule in the @NgModule
and tried to use `snackBar.open("hello")..`

The snackbar displayed and the text is shown twice:

Once in the snackbar and once in the top right.

I've opened the console and it has shown me this regarding

```
MdSnackBarContainer_html:1 :
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'initial'. Current value: 'visible'.
```

Has anybody encountered this before?
Thanks.

EDIT:

After removing it from the ngOnInit(), the error doesn't appear anymore..
But the snackbar is still buggy and the `cdk-visually-hidden` class is still visible..
any thoughts?

It's a problem to put the code here.. because it is in an offline network..
I'll dump the main parts though

app.module.ts:

```
    import {MdSnackBarModule, MdIconModule, OVERLAY_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/material";
    ...
    imports: [... MdSnackBarModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MdIConModule],
    providers: [ OVERLAY_PROVIDERS ]
    ..
```

.angular-cli.json:

```
    ...
    "styles": [
    "bootstrap.css"
    ],
    ..
```

templates.component.ts:

```
...
@Component({
..
providers: [...MdSnackBar]
..
})
..

public constructor(public snackBar: MdSnackBar...) 
...

public doSomething() {
    this.snackBar.open("Test test test");
}
...
```

By the way, when I don't use the action, the text does not even display on the snackbar.

Comment: see this article [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: Ok, thanks.. I've removed the call from ngOnInit()..
But it still displays the snackbar buggy... No error though..
Any thoughts?

Comment: sorry, can't help without the plunker

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: anyone........?

Comment: as I said we need a plunker, it's a tricky problem that required complete understanding of your setup

Comment: Please provide a plunker or example on github repo

Comment: As I explained, the whole code is in an offline network..
It is not possible for me to put it on plunker nor github

Comment: We do not need the whole code but rather a minimal reproduction.  We understand that sometimes it might be hard to extract essentials bits of code from a larger code-base but we really need to isolate the problem before we can help you.  Users often find coding problems themselves while preparing a minimal plunk

Comment: Actually I've found something new: a warning that says: 
"Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: .."

Answer (score 1):

I avoided this error by moving the snackBar.open method to the Component's constructor, rather than calling it in the ngOnInit method.